# Web.config Transformation during Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set up my build on Visual Studio Team Services but looks like that the Web.config transformation of my Web.Release.config doesn't work and I receive only the standard Web.config. What I do wrong or what parameter I miss.

[image]

Comment: I have never played with it with the TFS build but inside visual studio the transform only gets applied when you do a `Deploy` the config that is created when you just do a `Build` is the untransformed version.

Comment: it runs a command like this msbuild.exe "myProject.sln"  /p:Configuration=Release /p:platform="Any CPU" /p:VisualStudioVersion="15.0"

Comment: See this quuestion and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920146/using-msbuild-exe-to-publish-a-asp-net-mvc-4-project-with-the-cmd-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profile want work for me on the build server. I found this solution that works for me.

```
/p:outdir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\Release /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:PipelineDependsOnBuild=false
```

This part makes the difference:

```
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true
```

Comment: Since you solved the issue by yourself, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the transformation to happen msbuild needs to "deploy" the solution. I am not sure of the most correct way to do it, but a easy workaround would be add

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=SomeProfile
```

to the MSBuild Arguments option. You can then grab the files from wherever you configured the publish profile to put them and use those during your deployment.

Here is a very simple example of a `SomeProfile.pubxml` file that would put the published files in the artifact staging directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>$(BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY)\Release</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Using the MSBuild command args in TFS

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=SomeProfile
```

dropping the `/p:outDir`.

Comment: hmm on my build server i don't need a publishprofile because the copy to the azure server does the Release Management of Visual Studio Team Service

Comment: Perhaps create a profile that drops the transformed files in to `$(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory)\Release` and get rid of the `/p:outDir` in your build step. Profiles are just MSBuild scripts themselves and should be able to use the global variables.

Comment: ok. locally by setting a fixed path it works. how can i set the $(BuildArtifactStagingDirectory) in the profile configuration?

Comment: @cpiock added a example pubxml file that should work. Just create a new profile from inside visual studio then open the pubxml file and edit it as needed to have the settings you want.