# Are there any commands to publish a .net framework mvc project to a folder?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a `.net framework 4.7.2 mvc project` in visual studio.

From visual studio, I can publish this project to a folder by right click the project name -> select publish -> select Folder and so on. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

And now, I want to use some commands(For example, for a `.net core` project, we can use `dotnet publish` command to publish to a folder) to publish it to folder instead of using visual studio, does anyone know it？

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using MSBuild.exe to "Publish" a ASP.NET MVC 4 project with the cmd line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920146/using-msbuild-exe-to-publish-a-asp-net-mvc-4-project-with-the-cmd-line)

Comment: @Martheen, thanks for your reply. It seems that the msbuild.exe needs a .sln file. And my project is in a solution with other projects, so it does not have .sln file for this project, it only has .csproj file.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019#use-msbuild-at-a-command-prompt